# Python: List comprehension to assign different values

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm making a 2D list and I would like to initialize it with a list comprehension.  I would like it to do something like this:

```
[[x for i in range(3) if j <= 1: x=1 else x=2] for j in range(3)]
```

so it should return something like:

```
[[1,1,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [2,2,2]]
```

How might I go about doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears as though you're looking for something like this:

```
[[1 if j <= 1 else 2 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
```

The Python [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) is a bit different from what you might be used to if you're coming from something like C or Java:

> The expression `x if C else y` first evaluates *C* (*not x*); if *C* is true, *x* is evaluated and its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and its value is returned.

A slightly shorter way to do the same thing is:

```
[[1 if j <= 1 else 2]*3 for j in range(3)]
```

Comment: This is good since I can easily scale by changing the size of the range and change the conditional statement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Greg's response is correct, though a much simpler and faster expression to produce your desired result would be

```
[[j] * 3 for j in (1, 1, 2)]
```

i.e., remember that `for` need not apply to a `range` only;-), list-multiplication exists, and so on;-).

Comment: Does this allow the table to still be mutable? say I want to change [0][0] to 10, will that change any of the other values?

Comment: @Casey — No, it won't change any of the other values.

Comment: @Casey, @Ben is correct, each sublist is a distinct object (since they're made within a list comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
>>> [[(1 if j<1 else 2) for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
```

The second time j=1 so j<1 fails